# Show that f(x) is convex

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

Show that f(x) = inf{g(x1)+h(x2)} is convex subject to x1+x2=x and where g(.) and h(.) are convex functions.

Can I just go about this by using the regular definition of a convex function or which properties should I use? I know that the sum of convex functions is convex, but the infimum part confuses me. Thank you

Comment: Can you elaborate on your function a little? What is the infimum over?

Comment: It is infimum over x1 and x2, where x1+x2= x   @CameronWilliams

Comment: Please check out: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation for some help formatting the mathematics in your question.  It will go a long way to making it easier to read.

Comment: By the way, $f$ is called the "infimal convolution" of $g$ and $h$.  The infimal convolution is a standard topic in convex analysis books (in case you want to learn more about it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Suppose $f(a) = c$ and $f(b) = d$, and $0 < t < 1$.  Thus there exist $s_1$ and $s_2$ so 
$g(s_1) + h(a - s_1)$ is arbitrarily close to $c$, and $g(s_2) + h(b - s_2)$ is arbitrarily close to $d$.  Now taking $s = t s_1 + (1-t) s_2$, 
$$g(s) = g(t s_1 + (1-t) s_2) \le t g(s_1) + (1-t) g(s_2)$$
$$h(t a + (1-t) b - s) = h(t(a - s_1) + (1-t)(b-s_2))\le \ldots $$
so that
$$f(s) \le \ldots$$