# Show that $(f_1of_2)(x)=\inf \{f_1(x)+f_2(x):x=x_1+x_2\}$ is convex function

Tags: convex-analysis

Show that if $f_1(x_1), f_2(x_2)$ are convex functions then ,

$(f_1of_2)(x)=\inf \{f_1(x)+f_2(x):x=x_1+x_2\}$ is convex function

The definition of a convex function  f is that

$$f((1-t)x+ty)\le (1-t)f(x)+tf(y)\tag{1}$$

for all vectors $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n,t \in [0,1]$

so,

$(f_1of_2)((1-t)x+ty)=(f_1of_2)\{((1-t)x_1+ty_1)+((1-t)x_2+ty_2)\}$

$=\inf\{((1-t)x_1+ty_1)+((1-t)x_2+ty_2):x=x_1+x_2,y=y_1+y_2\}$

I am just stuck weather I can use Infimum properties or not someone can help ?

Comment: Are you assuming that the functions are bounded below? Otherwise the infimum may be $-\infty$.

Comment: Do you mean $(f_1of_2)(x)=\inf \{f_1(x_1)+f_2(x_2):x=x_1+x_2\}$ ?

Comment: @MartinR..NO SIR

Comment: NO what? It looks like the same question and has an answer. – Perhaps you can also respond to my first two comments.

Comment: Btw, this operation is called “[infimal convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate#Infimal_convolution).”

Comment: @MartinR.... I don't think so both are the same answers sir

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you are saying. Do you think that https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1244212 is a different question? Why?

Comment: @MartinR sorry sir I'm  so stressed with other things so can't pay attention to your comments yes sir both are the same..thank you so much for you patience